# Retrieving variables from a mySQL table to be used in another row in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I realize my question may be a bit trivial, but I am new to SQL/mySQL and have not found an answer to my question through google. SO this is the mySQL table I am working with.

```
create table Contribution
(
   ContributionID       int not null auto_increment,
   CreatedByUserId      int not null,
   StoryID              int not null,
   PreviousCID          int,
   NextCID              int,
   OriginalCID          int,
   Content              longblob not null,
   CreatedDate          datetime not null default 'getdate()',
   primary key (ContributionID)
);


alter table Contribution add constraint FK_CONTRIBU_REFERENCE_CONTRIBU2 foreign key (PreviousCID)
  references Contribution (ContributionID);


 alter table Contribution add constraint FK_CONTRIBU_REFERENCE_CONTRIBU3 foreign key (NextCID)
  references Contribution (ContributionID);

 alter table Contribution add constraint FK_CONTRIBU_REFERENCE_CONTRIBU4 foreign key (OriginalCID)
  references Contribution (ContributionID);
```

What I want to make is a php file to add a new contribution to this table. The new contribution will get a PreviousCID and NextCID from previous existing contributions. How can I get these as variables to add to my new contribution.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added the Foreign Keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i think you should make a foreign key for PreviousCID and NextCID to Table Contribution itself Like That:

```
--
-- Constraints for table `contribution`
--
ALTER TABLE `contribution`
ADD CONSTRAINT `contribution_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PreviousCID`) REFERENCES `contribution` (`ContributionID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `contribution_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`NextCID`) REFERENCES `contribution` (`ContributionID`);
```

than for php i dont understand what your approach to get:
***The new contribution will get a PreviousCID and NextCID from previous existing contributions***
but i think this will help you:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$existing_contribution_id = $_POST['SOME_VARIBALE']; //Here get existing contribution


//get from previous existing contributions
$query = "SELECT * FROM contribution Where =".$existing_contribution_id ;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

//insert new contribution
$sql = "INSERT INTO contribution (CreatedByUserId, StoryID, PreviousCID,
NextCID , OriginalCID , Content)VALUES ('some_user_id', 'some_story_id',".
$row['PreviousCID'].",".$row['NextCID'].", 'some_OriginalCID' , 'some_content')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a concise and clear answer, this is exactly what I wanted. The idea is to extract the PreviousCID and NextCID of the contribution I am currently handling and use it in the new contribution. Just a follow-up question while I'm here, if the id is auto incremented as shown above and therefore automatically generated, how can I get it and use it in another SQL statement? You don't have to answer if you don't want, but thanks again for the help

Comment: ok no problem you can use this statment:
    printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $conn->insert_id);
plaese make my answer as correct Answer

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. You were of great help.